# Need function in Excel Macro for Live streaming Stock Prices

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with this Macro function in Excel for Live Streaming of Stock Prices

T11 to T32 has prices streaming, value keeps changing every second
U11 to U32 will have values fed by User
V11 to V32 has difference in streaming prices vs value fed by User =(U15-T15)
Now the trouble part begins...

X11 to X32 has overall calculation

If values are greater than -1999, I have this function below but every time its going above 2000 it keeps beeping on 2100, 2200 thereby increasing the counter, I want this to stop unless values drop below -1999 and then comes back again to -2000,there should be a beep and counter should increase by 2

Same goes for value greater than -2500 & -3500

Below is the function

```
Private BlnAboveHundred As Boolean
Private IntCounter As Integer
Private IntCounter2 As Integer
Private IntCounter3 As Integer



Function StopCounterAF2(RngMeasure As Range)
    
    If RngMeasure.Value < (-1999) Then
        If BlnAboveHundred = False Then
            IntCounter = IntCounter + 1
            Call PlaySound("c:\windows\media\Stop1Filled.wav", _
            0, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)
            
            BlnAboveHundred = True
            
            Else
            
            BlnAboveHundred = True
            
            
        End If
        
    Else
    
        BlnAboveHundred = False
        
        
        
    End If
    
    StopCounterAF2 = IntCounter
    IntCounter = 0
End Function

Function StopCounterAG2(RngMeasure As Range)
    
    If RngMeasure.Value < (-2499) Then
        If BlnAboveHundred = False Then
            IntCounter2 = IntCounter2 + 1
            Call PlaySound("c:\windows\media\Stop2Filled.wav", _
            0, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)
            
            BlnAboveHundred = True
            
            Else
            
            BlnAboveHundred = True
            'IntCounter = 0
            
        End If
        
    Else
    
        BlnAboveHundred = False
        
    End If
    
    StopCounterAG2 = IntCounter2
    
End Function

Function StopCounterAH2(RngMeasure As Range)
    
    If RngMeasure.Value < (-2999) Then
        If BlnAboveHundred = False Then
            IntCounter3 = IntCounter3 + 1
            Call PlaySound("c:\windows\media\Stop3Filled.wav", _
            0, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)
            
            BlnAboveHundred = True
            
            Else
            
            BlnAboveHundred = True
            'IntCounter = 0
            
        End If
        
    Else
    
        BlnAboveHundred = False
        
    End If
    
    StopCounterAH2 = IntCounter3
    
End Function
```

Comment: This code works good to some extent unless below cells are populated, once the values in the below cell for eg X11 has value -2000 and X13 has values -1450, counter cell AF11 will increase by 1 but cell AF13 will also increase the counter by 1, that should not happen since its value have not increased by -2000

Comment: What is your question? Have you debugged your code? Are you stuck with a VBA problem or with your algorithm?

Comment: I believe its with VBA, the problem im facing is like i mentioned in comments above, once the values in the cell for eg X11 has value -2000 and X13 has values -1450, counter cell AF11 will increase by 1 but cell AF13 also increases the counter by 1, that should not happen since its value have not increased by -2000